# How to calculate Integral estimation in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, math, differential-equations

How can I do the following in python3 on the provided data set listed below?

**Problem**
Knowing that the `data.txt` has 2 columns:

xValues, where   ≤  ≤  , with  and  being some constants
gOfXValues

**1**Compute second order estimates of  ′()
**2**Compute second order estimates of  $g'(x)$ and $\int_a^b g(x)dx.$
Generally, we don't know that    values given from a random data sample is evenly separated.

**3**Plot  ()  and  ′() , print the integral.
**4**Based on the graph, what function do you think  ()  is?
**5**Verify this by qualitatively comparing the exact derivative and integral of your supposed  ()  with the numerical results obtained previously.

**What I have done so far**

```
import pandas as pd 

dataFrame = pd.read_csv('/Users/Files/data.txt', sep="\s+", names=['xValue','gOfXValue'])
dataFrame.info
dataFrame.head()

dgdxArray = []
gOfXValues = []

#iterate all observations and extract the columns as the independent and dependent variable
for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows(): 
    xValue = row['xValue']
    gOfXValue = row['gOfXValue']
    
    gOfXValues.append(gOfXValue)
    
    if index > 0: 
        h = 0.05
       
        difference = gOfXValue - gOfXValues[index-1] #check the difference between Current vs Previous value
        dgdx = difference / h    #get the Derivative
        dgdxArray.append(dgdx)   #add the derivative to an array so as to plot it
        
    

dgdxArray.insert(0,0.5) #hard code values

#plot the initial values provided 
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6,12))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax1.plot(dataFrame['xValue'], dataFrame['gOfXValue'])
ax1.set_title('Plot initial values x, g(x)')
ax1.set_xlabel('xValue')
ax1.set_ylabel('gOfXValue')


#Plot X value and the derivative on  y axis 
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax2.plot(dataFrame['xValue'], dgdxArray)
ax2.set_title('Plot x, derivativeOfGOfx')
ax2.set_xlabel('xValue')
ax2.set_ylabel('gOfXValue')
fig.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT_1**
How can I find the original function definition given that I only have access to xValue and gOfXvalue?

**Edit_2 based on comments with D Stanley**

#we know that in calculus g(x) = sin(x), g'(x) = cos(x), g(x)dx = - cos(x) + C

```
#Therefore: 
#calculate sin(x) and compare it to               g(x) provided 
#calculate f'(x)  and compare it to               g(x) provided 
#calculate integral of g(x)dx and compare it to   g(x) provided 

    constant = 2 #choose a random constant

#calculate the sin,cos and integral for existing x value  considering that the original function is sin
sinXfound = np.sin(dataFrame.xValue)
cosXfound = np.cos(dataFrame.xValue)
intXfound = - np.cos(dataFrame.xValue)  + constant

    
#create new columns in the original df with values calculate above
dataFrame['sinXfound'] = sinXfound
dataFrame['cosXfound'] = cosXfound
dataFrame['intXfound'] = intXfound

#find what is the difference between  sin,cos newly found and the original xValue provided in the request
differenceSinXfound = sinXfound - dataFrame['gOfXValue']
differenceCosXfound = cosXfound - dataFrame['gOfXValue']
differenceIntXfound = intXfound - dataFrame['gOfXValue']

#add columns to df
dataFrame['differenceSinXfound'] = differenceSinXfound
dataFrame['differenceCosXfound'] = differenceCosXfound
dataFrame['differenceIntXfound'] = differenceCosXfound

print(dataFrame)
```

[image]

**Edit_3 based on Lutz answer**

```
xValues = dataFrame.xValue
gofXValues = dataFrame.gOfXValue


firstDiffArray = []
def calculate_ALL_Divided_Differences():
    for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():
        if index > 0:
            xNow = row['xValue']
            gNow = row['gOfXValue']
            difference = (gofXValues[indexNow] - gofXValues[indexNow - 1]) / (xValues[indexNow] - xValues[indexNow -1])
            firstDiffArray.append(difference)
            

firstDividedDifference = (gofXValues[1] - gofXValues[0]) / (xValues[1] - xValues[0])

x0 = xValues[0]  
gOfXZero = gofXValues[0]


#Apply Newton's divided difference interpolation formula
for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows(): 
    
    if index > 0:
        xNow = row['xValue']
        gNow = row['gOfXValue']
        x_Minus_x0 = xNow - xValues[0]
        x_Minus_x1 = xNow - xValues[1]
        #Newton's divided difference interpolation formula is
        #f(x) = y0+(x-x0) f [x0,x1]+ (x-x0) * (x-x1) * f [x0,x1,x2]
        
        divided_Difference_Interpolation = gOfXZero + (xNow - x0) * firstDividedDifference + x_Minus_x0 * x_Minus_x1
```

**DataSet**

```
0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
3.157379551346525814e-02 1.031568549764810605e+00
6.314759102693051629e-02 1.063105631312673660e+00
9.472138654039577443e-02 1.094579807794844983e+00
1.262951820538610326e-01 1.125959705067717476e+00
1.578689775673262907e-01 1.157214042967250833e+00
1.894427730807915489e-01 1.188311666489717755e+00
2.210165685942568070e-01 1.219221576847691280e+00
2.525903641077220652e-01 1.249912962370308467e+00
2.841641596211873511e-01 1.280355229217014390e+00
3.157379551346525814e-01 1.310518031874168710e+00
3.473117506481178118e-01 1.340371303404112702e+00
3.788855461615830977e-01 1.369885285416546861e+00
4.104593416750483836e-01 1.399030557732340974e+00
4.420331371885136140e-01 1.427778067710209653e+00
4.736069327019788444e-01 1.456099159207016047e+00
5.051807282154441303e-01 1.483965601142838819e+00
5.367545237289094162e-01 1.511349615642326727e+00
5.683283192423747021e-01 1.538223905724288576e+00
5.999021147558398770e-01 1.564561682511917962e+00
6.314759102693051629e-01 1.590336691936528268e+00
6.630497057827704488e-01 1.615523240908179226e+00
6.946235012962356237e-01 1.640096222927107217e+00
7.261972968097009096e-01 1.664031143110431099e+00
7.577710923231661955e-01 1.687304142609184154e+00
7.893448878366314814e-01 1.709892022391332755e+00
8.209186833500967673e-01 1.731772266367076707e+00
8.524924788635619421e-01 1.752923063833377038e+00
8.840662743770272280e-01 1.773323331215339138e+00
9.156400698904925139e-01 1.792952733082778582e+00
9.472138654039576888e-01 1.811791702421020833e+00
9.787876609174229747e-01 1.829821460135725886e+00
1.010361456430888261e+00 1.847024033772298957e+00
1.041935251944353436e+00 1.863382275431223256e+00
1.073509047457818832e+00 1.878879878861460462e+00
1.105082842971284007e+00 1.893501395714874080e+00
1.136656638484749404e+00 1.907232250945481322e+00
1.168230433998214579e+00 1.920058757338174438e+00
1.199804229511679754e+00 1.931968129152434877e+00
1.231378025025145151e+00 1.942948494867437148e+00
1.262951820538610326e+00 1.952988909015839214e+00
1.294525616052075501e+00 1.962079363094462847e+00
1.326099411565540898e+00 1.970210795540986215e+00
1.357673207079006072e+00 1.977375100766707305e+00
1.389247002592471247e+00 1.983565137236369846e+00
1.420820798105936644e+00 1.988774734587002602e+00
1.452394593619401819e+00 1.992998699778669724e+00
1.483968389132867216e+00 1.996232822271006846e+00
1.515542184646332391e+00 1.998473878220378808e+00
1.547115980159797566e+00 1.999719633693477938e+00
1.578689775673262963e+00 1.999968846894156327e+00
1.610263571186728138e+00 1.999221269401275647e+00
1.641837366700193535e+00 1.997477646416338626e+00
1.673411162213658709e+00 1.994739716020657028e+00
1.704984957727123884e+00 1.991010207442792002e+00
1.736558753240589281e+00 1.986292838338002742e+00
1.768132548754054456e+00 1.980592311082403967e+00
1.799706344267519631e+00 1.973914308085537694e+00
1.831280139780985028e+00 1.966265486126021811e+00
1.862853935294450203e+00 1.957653469715929573e+00
1.894427730807915378e+00 1.948086843500509424e+00
1.926001526321380775e+00 1.937575143700825064e+00
1.957575321834845949e+00 1.926128848607841171e+00
1.989149117348311346e+00 1.913759368137436745e+00
2.020722912861776521e+00 1.900479032456751760e+00
2.052296708375241696e+00 1.886301079693208704e+00
2.083870503888706871e+00 1.871239642738459663e+00
2.115444299402172490e+00 1.855309735160411755e+00
2.147018094915637665e+00 1.838527236237377238e+00
2.178591890429102840e+00 1.820908875129262583e+00
2.210165685942568015e+00 1.802472214201578105e+00
2.241739481456033189e+00 1.783235631518890418e+00
2.273313276969498808e+00 1.763218302525168424e+00
2.304887072482963983e+00 1.742440180929283100e+00
2.336460867996429158e+00 1.720921978814716535e+00
2.368034663509894333e+00 1.698685145993306556e+00
2.399608459023359508e+00 1.675751848623608709e+00
2.431182254536824683e+00 1.652144947115186779e+00
2.462756050050290302e+00 1.627887973340858441e+00
2.494329845563755477e+00 1.603005107179614530e+00
2.525903641077220652e+00 1.577521152413588590e+00
2.557477436590685826e+00 1.551461512003107668e+00
2.589051232104151001e+00 1.524852162764468444e+00
2.620625027617616620e+00 1.497719629475682934e+00
2.652198823131081795e+00 1.470090958436002904e+00
2.683772618644546970e+00 1.441993690505579018e+00
2.715346414158012145e+00 1.413455833652134119e+00
2.746920209671477320e+00 1.384505835032010967e+00
2.778494005184942495e+00 1.355172552633428618e+00
2.810067800698408114e+00 1.325485226510211501e+00
2.841641596211873289e+00 1.295473449634670038e+00
2.873215391725338463e+00 1.265167138398678670e+00
2.904789187238803638e+00 1.234596502792368877e+00
2.936362982752268813e+00 1.203792016290152311e+00
2.967936778265734432e+00 1.172784385474099356e+00
2.999510573779199607e+00 1.141604519424951558e+00
3.031084369292664782e+00 1.110283498911275091e+00
3.062658164806129957e+00 1.078852545407476660e+00
3.094231960319595132e+00 1.047342989971558280e+00
3.125805755833060751e+00 1.015786242013636764e+00
3.157379551346525925e+00 9.842137579863630137e-01
3.188953346859991100e+00 9.526570100284420528e-01
3.220527142373456275e+00 9.211474545925236734e-01
3.252100937886921450e+00 8.897165010887251313e-01
3.283674733400387069e+00 8.583954805750482198e-01
3.315248528913852244e+00 8.272156145259004223e-01
3.346822324427317419e+00 7.962079837098479107e-01
3.378396119940782594e+00 7.654034972076313448e-01
3.409969915454247769e+00 7.348328616013215520e-01
3.441543710967712943e+00 7.045265503653301842e-01
3.473117506481178562e+00 6.745147734897881664e-01
3.504691301994643737e+00 6.448274473665716044e-01
3.536265097508108912e+00 6.154941649679892546e-01
3.567838893021574087e+00 5.865441663478661027e-01
3.599412688535039262e+00 5.580063094944210933e-01
3.630986484048504881e+00 5.299090415639968743e-01
3.662560279561970056e+00 5.022803705243168437e-01
3.694134075075435231e+00 4.751478372355316671e-01
3.725707870588900406e+00 4.485384879968926652e-01
3.757281666102365580e+00 4.224788475864115211e-01
3.788855461615830755e+00 3.969948928203856919e-01
3.820429257129296374e+00 3.721120266591415593e-01
3.852003052642761549e+00 3.478550528848133316e-01
3.883576848156226724e+00 3.242481513763912915e-01
3.915150643669691899e+00 3.013148540066936665e-01
3.946724439183157074e+00 2.790780211852837978e-01
3.978298234696622693e+00 2.575598190707169000e-01
4.009872030210087424e+00 2.367816974748317982e-01
4.041445825723553043e+00 2.167643684811096927e-01
4.073019621237018661e+00 1.975277857984218954e-01
4.104593416750483392e+00 1.790911248707376391e-01
4.136167212263949011e+00 1.614727637626225398e-01
4.167741007777413742e+00 1.446902648395883562e-01
4.199314803290879361e+00 1.287603572615404479e-01
4.230888598804344980e+00 1.136989203067911847e-01
4.262462394317809711e+00 9.952096754324846195e-02
4.294036189831275330e+00 8.624063186256325508e-02
4.325609985344740060e+00 7.387115139215894022e-02
4.357183780858205679e+00 6.242485629917493561e-02
4.388757576371671298e+00 5.191315649949035382e-02
4.420331371885136029e+00 4.234653028407053821e-02
4.451905167398601648e+00 3.373451387397807810e-02
4.483478962912066379e+00 2.608569191446230562e-02
4.515052758425531998e+00 1.940768891759592218e-02
4.546626553938997617e+00 1.370716166199725805e-02
4.578200349452462348e+00 8.989792557207887391e-03
4.609774144965927967e+00 5.260283979342972316e-03
4.641347940479392697e+00 2.522353583661263166e-03
4.672921735992858316e+00 7.787305987243531291e-04
4.704495531506323047e+00 3.115310584367314561e-05
4.736069327019788666e+00 2.803663065220618478e-04
4.767643122533254285e+00 1.526121779621192331e-03
4.799216918046719016e+00 3.767177728993265085e-03
4.830790713560184635e+00 7.001300221330386542e-03
4.862364509073649366e+00 1.122526541299739833e-02
4.893938304587114985e+00 1.643486276363004261e-02
4.925512100100580604e+00 2.262489923329280561e-02
4.957085895614045334e+00 2.978920445901367398e-02
4.988659691127510953e+00 3.792063690553715283e-02
5.020233486640975684e+00 4.701109098416056398e-02
5.051807282154441303e+00 5.705150513256296296e-02
5.083381077667906922e+00 6.803187084756523451e-02
5.114954873181371653e+00 7.994124266182545124e-02
5.146528668694837272e+00 9.276774905451867781e-02
5.178102464208302003e+00 1.064986042851256975e-01
5.209676259721767622e+00 1.211201211385396492e-01
5.241250055235233241e+00 1.366177245687767439e-01
5.272823850748697971e+00 1.529759662277010435e-01
5.304397646262163590e+00 1.701785398642742253e-01
5.335971441775628321e+00 1.882082975789789447e-01
5.367545237289093940e+00 2.070472669172214175e-01
5.399119032802559559e+00 2.266766687846610839e-01
5.430692828316024290e+00 2.470769361666227404e-01
5.462266623829489909e+00 2.682277336329232931e-01
5.493840419342954640e+00 2.901079776086668005e-01
5.525414214856420259e+00 3.126958573908157346e-01
5.556988010369884989e+00 3.359688568895683458e-01
5.588561805883350608e+00 3.599037770728926722e-01
5.620135601396816227e+00 3.844767590918209965e-01
5.651709396910280958e+00 4.096633080634712876e-01
5.683283192423746577e+00 4.354383174880819274e-01
5.714856987937211308e+00 4.617760942757109799e-01
5.746430783450676927e+00 4.886503843576732731e-01
5.778004578964142546e+00 5.160343988571614027e-01
5.809578374477607277e+00 5.439008407929837308e-01
5.841152169991072896e+00 5.722219322897904581e-01
5.872725965504537626e+00 6.009694422676585823e-01
5.904299761018003245e+00 6.301147145834531393e-01
5.935873556531468864e+00 6.596286965958874093e-01
5.967447352044933595e+00 6.894819681258308464e-01
5.999021147558399214e+00 7.196447707829856100e-01
6.030594943071863945e+00 7.500870376296912001e-01
6.062168738585329564e+00 7.807784231523084983e-01
6.093742534098795183e+00 8.116883335102823560e-01
6.125316329612259914e+00 8.427859570327489447e-01
6.156890125125725532e+00 8.740402949322825243e-01
6.188463920639190263e+00 9.054201922051545726e-01
6.220037716152655882e+00 9.368943686873262289e-01
6.251611511666121501e+00 9.684314502351897280e-01
6.283185307179586232e+00 9.999999999999997780e-01
```

Comment: this is not a question - this is you asking us to do your homework for you

Comment: @Qwerty Question: How can I find the function definition  for g(x) based on xValue and gOfXValue ?

Comment: It's not asking for the function definition - it's asking what you _think_ it is after graphing it. Have you done that yet? Have you calculated the derivative and integral (numerically)?

Comment: @DStanley, Yes I plotted  the functions, please see my code edit. I can't calculate the derivative and integral without knowing the function definition, can I?

Comment: @bibscy Great! what function do you _think_ that is?

Comment: @DStanley it looks like a sin function, monotonically increasing , then decreasing

Comment: @bibscy I agree. So how would you compare the derivative and intergral of a `sin` function to your results?

Comment: @DStanley 1.  The derivative of a ```sin``` function is equal with ```cos```, and the integral of ```sin``` is ```cos + C```. 2. So,  I could do a ```for loop``` through all x values and apply 
```numpy.sin()``` on each ```x```, then I would check if the output value is equal with ```gOfXValue``` already obtained from the file provided in the exercise. 3. Then, I know  that the integral of ```sin``` is ```cos()+C```, so I could compare this value too agains xValue, already given in the requirement,

Comment: @bibscy That sounds like a good plan. To answer the actual question, you can't find the actual function definition _just_ from the numerical values. But that's not what the assignment is asking.

Comment: @DStanley I'll get down to work. After I complete what I've said above, I'll post my findings. Thanks a lot for leading me!!!

Comment: @DStanley I've added an update in Edit_2. Where should I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivative is wrong, at this level it should be

```
(gofx[i]-gofx[i-1]) / (x[i]-x[i-1])
```

But this is only a first order approximation of the derivative, the task asks for a second error order. That is, for the derivative at `x[i]`, you have to take the interpolation polynomial through the points `x[i-1], x[i], x[i+1]` and their values

```
g[x[i]] + g[x[i],x[i+1]] * (x-x[i]) + g[x[i],x[i-1],x[i+1]] * (x-x[i])*(x-x[i-1])
```

and compute the derivative of it at `x=x[i]`. Or alternatively, from the Taylor expansion you know that

```
    (gofx[i]-gofx[i-1]) / (x[i]-x[i-1]) = g'(x[i]) - 0.5*g''(x[i])*(x[i]-x[i-1])+...
    (gofx[i+1]-gofx[i]) / (x[i+1]-x[i]) = g'(x[i]) + 0.5*g''(x[i])*(x[i+1]-x[i])+...
```

Combining both you can eliminate the term with `g''(x[i])`.

so if

```
dx = x[1:]-x[:-1]
dg = g[1:]-g[:-1]
```

are the simple differences, then the first order derivative with second error order is

```
dg_dx = dg/dx
diff_g = ( dx[:-1]*(dg_dx[1:]) + dx[1:]*(dg_dx[:-1]) ) / (dx[1:]+dx[:-1])
```

This is written so that the nature as convex combination becomes obvious.

---

For the integral, the cumulative trapezoidal quadrature should be sufficient.

```
sum( 0.5*(g[:-1]+g[1:])*(x[1:]-x[:-1]) )
```

Use the cumulative sum if you want the anti-derivative as function (table).

You might want to extract the data into numpy arrays directly, there should be functions in pandas that do that.

---

In total I get the short script

```
x,g = np.loadtxt('so65602720.data').T

%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
plt.subplot(131)
plt.plot(x,g,x,np.sin(x)+1); plt.legend(["table g values", "$1+sin(x)$"]); plt.grid(); 

dx = x[1:]-x[:-1]
dg = g[1:]-g[:-1]
dg_dx = dg/dx
diff_g = ( dx[:-1]*(dg_dx[1:]) + dx[1:]*(dg_dx[:-1]) ) / (dx[1:]+dx[:-1])

plt.subplot(132)
plt.plot(x,g,x[1:-1],diff_g); plt.legend(["g", "g'"]); plt.grid(); 

int_g = np.cumsum(0.5*(g[1:]+g[:-1])*(x[1:]-x[:-1]))

plt.subplot(133)
plt.plot(x[1:],int_g,x,x); plt.legend(["integral of g","diagonal"]); plt.grid(); 

plt.tight_layout(); plt.show()
```

resulting in the plot collection

[image: plots of function, derivative and integral]

showing first that indeed the data is of the function `g(x)=1+sin(x)`, that the derivative correctly looks like the cosine and the integral is `x+1-cos(x)`.

Comment: what do you mean by " you have to take the interpolation polynomial through the points x[i-1], x[i], x[i+1] and their values and compute the derivative of it." Can you show in code?

Comment: Look up Lagrange or Newton interpolation. The second approach will give the same result.

Comment: I think I have managed to implement Newton Interpolation based on https://people.clas.ufl.edu/maia/files/Lecture3.2.pdf. Could you please advise if it is correct and the next step from here? See ```Edit 3``` Many thanks

Comment: I posted an answer to prevent cluttering the original question more. Please comment on this with any suggestions as I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I am positing this as a placeholder to get suggestions.

```
#Try1
import pandas as pd 
from sympy import * 
dataFrame = pd.read_csv('/data_2.txt', sep="\s+", names=['xValue','gOfXValue'],float_precision='round_trip', nrows=200)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 200)

xValues = dataFrame.xValue
gofXValues = dataFrame.gOfXValue


#Compute second order estimate for g'(x)
firstDiffArray = [] 
def calculate_ALL_Divided_Differences():
    for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():
        if index > 0:
            xNow = row['xValue']
            gNow = row['gOfXValue']
            difference = (gofXValues[index] - gofXValues[index - 1]) / (xValues[index] - xValues[index -1])
            firstDiffArray.append(difference)


calculate_ALL_Divided_Differences() 


#Plot x and g'(x) that I've found
xValuesLessOne = xValues[:-1]
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6,12))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax1.plot(xValuesLessOne, firstDiffArray)
ax1.set_title('x vs g Derivated')
ax1.set_xlabel('xValue')
ax1.set_ylabel('g Derivated')
fig.tight_layout() 
plt.show()



firstDiffArray.insert(0,0) #insert the first row as 0 to have same 200 rows data shape
dataFrame['derivative_For_gOfX'] = firstDiffArray #create column for the derivative of gOfX


###Find integral g(x)dx
def findIntegral(): 


    for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows(): 
        if index < 199:
            
            xNow = xValues[index]
            xNowPlus_1 = xValues[index + 1]
            
            gNow = gofXValues[index]
            gNowPlus_1 =  gofXValues[index + 1]
            
            intg = (gNowPlus_1 - gNow) * (xNowPlus_1 - xNow)
            integralPoints.append(intg)
            
            intgTrapez = 0.5*(gofXValues[i+1] + gofXValues[i]) * (xValues[i+1] - xValues[i])
            trapezIntegralPoints.append(intgTrapez)
            
   
    
#integral found numerically
integralFound = findIntegral()
sumIntegralPoints = sum(integralPoints)
sumtrapezIntegralPoints = sum(trapezIntegralPoints)



print('IntegralFound', sumIntegralPoints)
print('TrapezIntegral', sumtrapezIntegralPoints)
```

[image]

```
IntegralFound -2.7538735181131813e-17
TrapezIntegral 8.328014461189756
       xValue  gOfXValue  derivative_For_gOfX
0    0.000000   1.000000             0.000000
1    0.031574   1.031569             0.999834
2    0.063148   1.063106             0.998837
3    0.094721   1.094580             0.996845
4    0.126295   1.125960             0.993859
5    0.157869   1.157214             0.989882
6    0.189443   1.188312             0.984919
7    0.221017   1.219222             0.978974
8    0.252590   1.249913             0.972052
9    0.284164   1.280355             0.964162
10   0.315738   1.310518             0.955311
11   0.347312   1.340371             0.945508
12   0.378886   1.369885             0.934762
13   0.410459   1.399031             0.923084
14   0.442033   1.427778             0.910486
15   0.473607   1.456099             0.896981
16   0.505181   1.483966             0.882581
17   0.536755   1.511350             0.867302
18   0.568328   1.538224             0.851158
19   0.599902   1.564562             0.834166
20   0.631476   1.590337             0.816342
21   0.663050   1.615523             0.797704
22   0.694624   1.640096             0.778271
23   0.726197   1.664031             0.758063
24   0.757771   1.687304             0.737099
25   0.789345   1.709892             0.715400
26   0.820919   1.731772             0.692987
27   0.852492   1.752923             0.669885
28   0.884066   1.773323             0.646114
29   0.915640   1.792953             0.621699
30   0.947214   1.811792             0.596665
31   0.978788   1.829821             0.571035
32   1.010361   1.847024             0.544837
33   1.041935   1.863382             0.518096
34   1.073509   1.878880             0.490838
35   1.105083   1.893501             0.463090
36   1.136657   1.907232             0.434881
37   1.168230   1.920059             0.406239
38   1.199804   1.931968             0.377192
39   1.231378   1.942948             0.347768
40   1.262952   1.952989             0.317998
41   1.294526   1.962079             0.287911
42   1.326099   1.970211             0.257537
43   1.357673   1.977375             0.226907
44   1.389247   1.983565             0.196050
45   1.420821   1.988775             0.164998
46   1.452395   1.992999             0.133781
47   1.483968   1.996233             0.102431
48   1.515542   1.998474             0.070978
49   1.547116   1.999720             0.039455
50   1.578690   1.999969             0.007893
51   1.610264   1.999221            -0.023677
52   1.641837   1.997478            -0.055224
53   1.673411   1.994740            -0.086715
54   1.704985   1.991010            -0.118120
55   1.736559   1.986293            -0.149408
56   1.768133   1.980592            -0.180546
57   1.799706   1.973914            -0.211505
58   1.831280   1.966265            -0.242252
59   1.862854   1.957653            -0.272758
60   1.894428   1.948087            -0.302993
61   1.926002   1.937575            -0.332925
62   1.957575   1.926129            -0.362525
63   1.989149   1.913759            -0.391764
64   2.020723   1.900479            -0.420613
65   2.052297   1.886301            -0.449042
66   2.083871   1.871240            -0.477023
67   2.115444   1.855310            -0.504529
68   2.147018   1.838527            -0.531533
69   2.178592   1.820909            -0.558006
70   2.210166   1.802472            -0.583923
71   2.241739   1.783236            -0.609258
72   2.273313   1.763218            -0.633986
73   2.304887   1.742440            -0.658081
74   2.336461   1.720922            -0.681521
75   2.368035   1.698685            -0.704281
76   2.399608   1.675752            -0.726340
77   2.431182   1.652145            -0.747674
78   2.462756   1.627888            -0.768263
79   2.494330   1.603005            -0.788086
80   2.525904   1.577521            -0.807124
81   2.557477   1.551462            -0.825357
82   2.589051   1.524852            -0.842767
83   2.620625   1.497720            -0.859337
84   2.652199   1.470091            -0.875051
85   2.683773   1.441994            -0.889892
86   2.715346   1.413456            -0.903846
87   2.746920   1.384506            -0.916900
88   2.778494   1.355173            -0.929039
89   2.810068   1.325485            -0.940252
90   2.841642   1.295473            -0.950528
91   2.873215   1.265167            -0.959856
92   2.904789   1.234597            -0.968228
93   2.936363   1.203792            -0.975635
94   2.967937   1.172784            -0.982069
95   2.999511   1.141605            -0.987524
96   3.031084   1.110283            -0.991994
97   3.062658   1.078853            -0.995476
98   3.094232   1.047343            -0.997965
99   3.125806   1.015786            -0.999460
100  3.157380   0.984214            -0.999958
101  3.188953   0.952657            -0.999460
102  3.220527   0.921147            -0.997965
103  3.252101   0.889717            -0.995476
104  3.283675   0.858395            -0.991994
105  3.315249   0.827216            -0.987524
106  3.346822   0.796208            -0.982069
107  3.378396   0.765403            -0.975635
108  3.409970   0.734833            -0.968228
109  3.441544   0.704527            -0.959856
110  3.473118   0.674515            -0.950528
111  3.504691   0.644827            -0.940252
112  3.536265   0.615494            -0.929039
113  3.567839   0.586544            -0.916900
114  3.599413   0.558006            -0.903846
115  3.630986   0.529909            -0.889892
116  3.662560   0.502280            -0.875051
117  3.694134   0.475148            -0.859337
118  3.725708   0.448538            -0.842767
119  3.757282   0.422479            -0.825357
120  3.788855   0.396995            -0.807124
121  3.820429   0.372112            -0.788086
122  3.852003   0.347855            -0.768263
123  3.883577   0.324248            -0.747674
124  3.915151   0.301315            -0.726340
125  3.946724   0.279078            -0.704281
126  3.978298   0.257560            -0.681521
127  4.009872   0.236782            -0.658081
128  4.041446   0.216764            -0.633986
129  4.073020   0.197528            -0.609258
130  4.104593   0.179091            -0.583923
131  4.136167   0.161473            -0.558006
132  4.167741   0.144690            -0.531533
133  4.199315   0.128760            -0.504529
134  4.230889   0.113699            -0.477023
135  4.262462   0.099521            -0.449042
136  4.294036   0.086241            -0.420613
137  4.325610   0.073871            -0.391764
138  4.357184   0.062425            -0.362525
139  4.388758   0.051913            -0.332925
140  4.420331   0.042347            -0.302993
141  4.451905   0.033735            -0.272758
142  4.483479   0.026086            -0.242252
143  4.515053   0.019408            -0.211505
144  4.546627   0.013707            -0.180546
145  4.578200   0.008990            -0.149408
146  4.609774   0.005260            -0.118120
147  4.641348   0.002522            -0.086715
148  4.672922   0.000779            -0.055224
149  4.704496   0.000031            -0.023677
150  4.736069   0.000280             0.007893
151  4.767643   0.001526             0.039455
152  4.799217   0.003767             0.070978
153  4.830791   0.007001             0.102431
154  4.862365   0.011225             0.133781
155  4.893938   0.016435             0.164998
156  4.925512   0.022625             0.196050
157  4.957086   0.029789             0.226907
158  4.988660   0.037921             0.257537
159  5.020233   0.047011             0.287911
160  5.051807   0.057052             0.317998
161  5.083381   0.068032             0.347768
162  5.114955   0.079941             0.377192
163  5.146529   0.092768             0.406239
164  5.178102   0.106499             0.434881
165  5.209676   0.121120             0.463090
166  5.241250   0.136618             0.490838
167  5.272824   0.152976             0.518096
168  5.304398   0.170179             0.544837
169  5.335971   0.188208             0.571035
170  5.367545   0.207047             0.596665
171  5.399119   0.226677             0.621699
172  5.430693   0.247077             0.646114
173  5.462267   0.268228             0.669885
174  5.493840   0.290108             0.692987
175  5.525414   0.312696             0.715400
176  5.556988   0.335969             0.737099
177  5.588562   0.359904             0.758063
178  5.620136   0.384477             0.778271
179  5.651709   0.409663             0.797704
180  5.683283   0.435438             0.816342
181  5.714857   0.461776             0.834166
182  5.746431   0.488650             0.851158
183  5.778005   0.516034             0.867302
184  5.809578   0.543901             0.882581
185  5.841152   0.572222             0.896981
186  5.872726   0.600969             0.910486
187  5.904300   0.630115             0.923084
188  5.935874   0.659629             0.934762
189  5.967447   0.689482             0.945508
190  5.999021   0.719645             0.955311
191  6.030595   0.750087             0.964162
192  6.062169   0.780778             0.972052
193  6.093743   0.811688             0.978974
194  6.125316   0.842786             0.984919
195  6.156890   0.874040             0.989882
196  6.188464   0.905420             0.993859
197  6.220038   0.936894             0.996845
198  6.251612   0.968431             0.998837
199  6.283185   1.000000             0.999834
```

Comment: The segment term for the trapezoidal method are `0.5*(g[i+1]+g[i])*(x[i+1]-x[i])`, there is some difference to the term you used.

Comment: I don't know the function definition of ```g````, therefore I can't apply your suggestion```0.5*(g[i+1]+g[i])*(x[i+1]-x[i])```

Comment: `g` is short for `gofXValues`, while `x` stands for `xValues`. For mathematical variables and functions used in a dense computation you are allowed to use single letter or otherwise short names. If you program a GUI then there are many objects that are rather seldom used, so longer "speaking" names are recommended. // I added this and a differentiation formula to my answer.

Comment: Now I am confused, after applying the trapezoidal method, I get completely different values see my integrals printed. What have I done wrong? ```IntegralFound -2.7538735181131813e-17``` and   
```TrapezIntegral 8.328014461189756```

Comment: Your g-values are all positive between 0 and 2. The integral can not be negative, and not close to zero. More precisely, the integral of `1+sin(x)` from `0` to `2*pi` is `2*pi`, so both values are corrupt or the tabulated function is not precisely the shifted sine. But the value 8.328... is more realistic than the other one.